# Why Core String Object Assigned to Custom String Class Reference

Tags: java, string, object, jvm, package

Case 1:
I have defined a package, java.lang and define an class String in this package:

```
package java.lang;
public class String {
    String name = "ABC";
}
```

Here I am able to assign the reference(name) of my custom String class to the object("ABC") of String class from core java library.
**Why does compiler allow to do so?**

Case 2:
when i defined same String class in other some package say java.langplus:

```
package java.langplus;
public class String {
    String name = "ABC"; //compiler error
}
```

then  that line `String name = "ABC";` throws compiler error, as expected, because I am assigning the reference of My custom String class from java.langplus class to the Object of core String class.

Comment: I don't see a way how the compiler can distinguish the custom class and the core class at all because they have the same full qualified name.

Comment: use fully qualified class name for either of them.

Comment: I'd guess (1) has something to do with the need to bootstrap the "real" `String` class in order to define things in the classes needed to load the `String` class, so the compiler treats it specially. Interesting.

Comment: There is no “custom String class”. When you declare a class `String` in package `java.lang`, that’s `java.lang.String` without any discussion. The package *is* the mechanism to tell different classes named `String` apart. You can’t have two different class named `java.lang.String` in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At run time,  every class in java is defined by its classloader plus its package.

At compile time we don't have class loader, so compiler does type checking, for reference assignment, using package name only.

In case of Case 2, the package name is different for core String: "ABC" and String reference: *name*, which is from java.langplus package.

In case 1, even though compiler finds ***your*** String class in ***your*** java.lang same as the class of "ABC" i.e. core library String class, it is going to fail at runtime.